# The bundle is invalid. New apps and updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm unable to submit App at app store. I am using Xcode 4.6.2, and when I am uploading the app I am getting the error "The bundle is invalid. New apps and updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public"

Comment: I'm guessing there's more to that message? Does it really end in "public" ?

Comment: Yes, this is. I am getting exactly "The bundle is invalid. New apps and updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Per Apple, all new apps and app updates submitted must be built with Xcode 5 and the iOS 7 SDK as of February 1st 2014.

Update to Xcode 5, rebuild and test. Then you should be able to submit.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 5.1 (released today) and the iOS 7.1 SDK, and am still getting the same error message (ending in 'public').

Comment: how did you fix it ? I'm running into the same problem!! Please help

Comment: @Maystro Double check to make sure Xcode is completely up to date and try the whole process again (archive/submission).

Answer (score 34):

I ran into the exact same issue today with Xcode 5.1 and iOS 7.1 SDK.

The solution was to update my Xcode to 5.1.1. After that I re-archived and re-submitted my app, and it went through just fine. Here is the related Apple's announcement:

> Starting May 15, 2014, new apps and app updates submitted to the App
>   Store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1. This release is available
>   through Software Update on the Mac App Store. (https://developer.apple.com/news/)

Comment: I had this problem with Xcode 5.1.1, and my solution was just to restart Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

```
New apps and updates submitted to the App store must be built with Xcode 5 and ios 7 SDK.
```

Comment: Application loader message

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue you MUST go to the APP STORE and install the update of Xcode.

Comment: Downloads are also available through the Developer Portal.