# Signing iOS app using XCode 4?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to generate certificate in-order to sign my iOS apps build in PhoneGap. The below is what apple says now if i am correct Xcode has various version the one i have is 4 on mountain lion OS(VM Ware machine). is the process still the same ? or do i need the latest version of XCode which is 5.0 to sign my apps and also does not run on Mountain lion OS?

> Request Certificates with Xcode
>
> Xcode is the easiest way to request certificates. Connect your device
>   to your Mac and click Use for Development in Xcode's Organizer window.
>   Sign in with the Apple ID associated with your iOS Developer Program
>   membership and Xcode will automatically generate your certificates.

Answer (score 1):

Process is the same. You don't need newer version of XCode. Just follow given instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have apple developer account before you proceed.

Go to **general** > **Team** > **Add an account**

[image]

After you enter your details then go to **general** tab back.

Click **Fix issue** button and your provision profile already automatically generated in apple developer website by xcode. Then download that provisioning profile then install into your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Apple is not accepting builds generated from XCode 4 or older. You need to sign it from XCode 5. Request for certificates can also be made using it.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061217/the-bundle-is-invalid-new-apps-and-updates-submitted-to-the-app-store-must-be-b) issue comes up if you submit it after signing from older XCode.