# iTunesConnect error "You must choose a build."

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode5, app-store-connect

[image]
I am trying to submit my new app to app store but apple has changed its website interface and when I update metadata and keywords and hit “submit for review” it gives error “you must choose a build”
in my Xcode 5.1 i i want validate my app ,so i have this error some help plz

Comment: Did you check this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061217/the-bundle-is-invalid-new-apps-and-updates-submitted-to-the-app-store-must-be-b

Answer (score 0):

New apps and updates submitted to the App store must be built with **Xcode 5.1.1** or **Later**, or **Application Laoder 2.9.2** or **Later**.

[image]