# Submitting app to apple store (validation issue)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

[image]

I am using Xcode 6.1.1 and using iOS 7 SDK (tried iOS 8 too). All provisional profiles are setup correctly.
How to resolve this issue

Comment: you are using GM version or beta version? Check Xcode > About

Comment: Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)

Comment: possible duplicate of [The bundle is invalid. New apps and updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061217/the-bundle-is-invalid-new-apps-and-updates-submitted-to-the-app-store-must-be-b)

Comment: If all is ok then please restart your mac and open your x Code and try again. Sometimes apple give weird issues and I also faced that. Hope it should work for you too.

Comment: error is saying about Xcode beta

Comment: I am trying this from last 2 days .. Same issue

Comment: @CSchulz: This is not a duplicate. He has mentioned above that he is using x Code 6.1.

Comment: Alright, so he needs to switch back to a final version.

Comment: Yes, please go to apple updates in your mac and check everything is up to date.

Comment: Everything is up to date

Comment: Do you have x Code 5.1?

Comment: I developed in swift and I am using Xcode 6.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Goto Xcode --> Preferences --> Location check "Command Line Tools" and select latest Xcode version.

[image]

Comment: have you added test flight beta sdk?

Comment: Yes I've done test flight testing. All ok .. but when I am submitting for review on apple appstore, it shows : "Apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 5.1.1 or later, and iOS 7 SDK or later. Don’t submit apps built with beta software."

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6.1.1 is making a problem when validating

xcode 6.0.1 working perfectly

Thanks everyone